# How to disable direct input in Textfield with DropdownMenu composable?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

While using a `DropdownMenu` composable with a `Textfield`, how do I prevent the user from directly typing into the `Textfield`?

Setting the field's `enabled` parameter to `false` completely deactivates the field which is not desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextField has a parameter called `readOnly`, you can set it to true to prevent it from being modified.

> readOnly controls the editable state of the TextField. When true, the text
> field can not be modified, however, a user can focus it and copy text
> from it. Read-only text  fields are usually used to display pre-filled
> forms that user can not edit

Comment: Could you add a link to the source of your quoted text?

Comment: @rmtheis this is from `TextField` source code itself. You can hover over it or cmd/ctrl click and check out kdoc.